# Create a 10x10 field of cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a field of cells. The field has a size of 10x10. When reaching a maximum count of cells in a row, it should start a new row.

Currently all my cell divs are placed below.

```js
function initGame() {

    var mapSize = 10; // create a field of 10x10
    var cellsPerRow = 10; // 10 cells per row

    for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
            createCell(x, y); // create a cell on index x (horizontal) and y (vertical)
        }
    }
}

function createCell(x, y) {

    // store this cell position to a data class

    var cellDiv = $("<div></div>"); // create the cell div
    cellDiv.addClass("cell"); // add some css
    $(document.body).append(cellDiv); // add the cell div to the parent
}
```

```css
.cell{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="initGame()">

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Please describe what you want and how the current code differs from that.

Comment: The cells should fill the columns to the right. There should be 10 cells per row

Comment: Why not just create a table? (And doable in CSS if each row is in a separate element with `display: table/table-row/table-cel;`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create wrapper for each 10 cell.**

```js
function initGame() {

    var mapSize = 10; // create a field of 10x10
    var cellsPerRow = 10; // 10 cells per row

    for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {

        $(document.body).append("<div>");
       
        for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
            createCell(x, y); // create a cell on index x (horizontal) and y (vertical)
        }
        $(document.body).append("</div>");

    }
}

function createCell(x, y) {

    // store this cell position to a data class

    var cellDiv = $("<div></div>"); // create the cell div
    cellDiv.addClass("cell"); // add some css
    $(document.body).append(cellDiv); // add the cell div to the parent
}
```

```css
.cell{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    background: red;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="initGame()">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

use   `display:inline-block;` for .cells and to stop 10 each row add a `<br>` tag after 10 divs in row.

```js
function initGame() {

  var mapSize = 10; // create a field of 10x10
  var cellsPerRow = 10; // 10 cells per row

  for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {

      createCell(x, y);

    }
    $(document.body).append("<br>");
  }
}

function createCell(x, y) {

  // store this cell position to a data class

  var cellDiv = $("<div></div>"); // create the cell div
  cellDiv.addClass("cell"); // add some css
  $(document.body).append(cellDiv); // add the cell div to the parent
}
```

```css
.cell {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="initGame()">

</body>
```

Comment: The number of cells per row in you solution depends on the width available.
OP clearly wants a 10x10 field of cells.

Comment: Simon's right, but all you need to do to fix this is place the cells in a container with `width` of cellWidth*10

Comment: i got it. check my solution now.

Comment: No you dont got it because of the fact that you get 9 cells per row....

Comment: @RickBronger My bad. that was loop initialisation to 1. corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning and set for each of them css property. Here is the fiddle

```js
function initGame() {

  var mapSize = 10; // create a field of 10x10
  var cellsPerRow = 10; // 10 cells per row

  for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
      createCell(x, y); // create a cell on index x (horizontal) and y (vertical)
    }
  }
}

function createCell(x, y) {

  // store this cell position to a data class

  var cellDiv = $("<div></div>"); // create the cell div
  cellDiv.addClass("cell"); // add some css
  cellDiv.css({
    left: Math.floor(x*50),
    top: Math.floor(y*50)
  });
  $(document.body).append(cellDiv); // add the cell div to the parent
}

initGame()
```

```css
.cell{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row `div` that contains multiple cell `div`

```js
function initGame() {
  const rows = 10;
  const columns = 10;

  for(let r=0;r<rows;r++){
    let row = createRow(r);
    for(let c=0;c<columns;c++){
      createCell(row, r, c);
    }
  }
}

function createRow(rowNumber){
  let row = document.createElement('DIV');
  row.className += ' row'
  $(document.body).append(row);
  return row;
}

function createCell(domRow, rowNumber, columnNumber){
  let column = document.createElement('DIV');
  column.className += ' cell';
  $(domRow).append(column);
}
```

```css
.cell{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: tomato;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="initGame()">

</body>
```